# Hibernate - automatic created_date and updated_date from the database

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa, orm

We need to add two columns in each table - created_date and updated_date.
The type of database can be any of the following: Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, CouchDB.

The two columns should store the date as well as the time.
created_date should be filled only when a row is created.
updated_date should be filled every time a row is updated (during creation time too).

The solution is for a cloud where a lot of Hibernate JVMs will be running.
Since there is no single JVM, they may occasionally go out of sync in time.
So we do NOT want the solution to populate JVM time in these two columns.

Is there a DB-agnostic way to do this in Hibernate?
We would like to put the responsibility of date creation/updation on the DB itself.
Triggers would be the last option we want to try as that would be cumbersome to generate for each table.

Ideal solution would be to have some kind of annotation in JPA/Hibernate which will dictate the ORM tool to create or update the date from DB during insert/update.

Comment: I tried using the following SQL (for Oracle):
<pre>
create table tmptmp (
  id number(10), 
  ct TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  ut TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE TIMESTAMP
);
</pre>

But it gives me error:
Error at Command Line:5 Column:42
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution and its very well explained here: [Custom SQL for Columns - PrismoSkills](http://prismoskills.appspot.com/lessons/Hibernate/Chapter_08_-_Custom_SQL_for_Columns.jsp)

This solution is DB agnostic and Hibernate friendly.